# Raspberry Pi 3のWiFi設定をBLEで行うのは悪手ですか？

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth

お世話になっております。

Raspberry Pi 3にはWiFiとBLEがボードに組み込まれていて便利です。しかし有線LANと異なり無線LANはSSIDの指定やパスワード入力などが必要です。具体的には`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`ファイルを編集しなければなりません。通常はキーボードとディスプレイを接続して無線LANの設定を済ませ、その後はsshなどでディスプレイやキーボードなしに操作できるようになります。

しかしそれは不便なので次のようなアイディアを思いつきました。スマホやPCなどでBLEのデバイスを検索し、該当Raspberry Piを見つけたら、BLE経由でSSIDやパスワードを設定できたら便利ではないでしょうか。そうすればキーボードやディスプレイなしにインターネットにつながります。

これはありふれたアイディアだと思うのですが、日本語英語で色々検索してもこのような事例は見つかりませんでした。私自身、BLEの扱いには全然慣れていないので、もしかするとこれはできない、やるべきではないなど悪手なのではないかと不安に思うのですが、ご意見をいただければ幸いです。もし技術的に問題なくそうした設定が行えるとしたら、参考になる情報（URL, 本など）をご紹介いただければ助かります。

ここでのSSIDの設定は、新品のRaspberry Piの設定ではなく、自宅で開発したRaspberry Piをどこか友人の家などに持ち込むことを想定しています。つまり、Raspberry Piの電源を投入したらあらかじめ作成しておいたプログラム（node.jsが多いようです）が`wpa_supplicant.conf`を書き換えたり、サービスを再起動するのに必要な権限（root?）で起動し、スマホからの接続を待機している状況になるものです。

よろしくお願いします。

## 2016年10月31日追記

まだ試していないのですが、Wi-Fi SmartConfigというものを見つけました。

これは他のIoTハードで同じような問題をどのように解決しているか調べていて、[Sansaire Delta](https://sansaire.com/sansaire-delta/)という製品の説明で

> CONNECTIVITY  Wifi with SmartConfig pairing

という記述を見つけました。

Comment: 不可能ではないと思いますが、例えば[Volumio](https://volumio.org/)(v2)は自身をWi-FiのHotspotにして他の機器から接続できるようにし、Web UIで設定できるようにしています。
こういったやり方はどうでしょう？

Comment: Volumio見てみました。今まで知らなかったLinuxのディストリビューションでした。ただWiFiの設定については有線で接続した後に http://volumio.local/index.php で管理画面にアクセスするようで、やや手間がかかるかも知れません。できることなら、コンピュータのことがわからない年配の方（ただしWiFiは孫とか誰かが設定したのがある）でも持ち込むだけで使えるものを目指していますので、もう少し継続して調査してみます。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

目的が

> できることなら、コンピュータのことがわからない年配の方（‌​ただしWiFiは孫とか誰かが設定したのが‌​ある）でも持ち込むだけで使えるものを目指‌​しています

であれば、ラスパイをWPS対応されてはいかがでしょうか。

ただし、以下の留意点があります。
・ラズパイ側のWPS開始トリガーをどうするか（電源投入後、知っているSSIDが見つからなければ、自動でWPS開始するなど）
・WPS対応のWiFiアクセスポイントが必須
・WPSで設定が成功したかをわかりやすくするため、ラズパイ側にLEDなど追加検討の余地あり

Comment: コメントが遅くなりました、申し訳ありません。WPS対応は考えていなかった対応なのでその線で考えてみます。ありがとうございます。